# How could I reuse variables that are inside methods in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, class, oop, subclass

Android Studio says a variable must be declared final, so you can use it in more than one method in the same class. But is there another way to do that, because I would have to modify the variable and once you declare it final you can't change it.

This variable is inside a void onComplete(whatever) and I need to use it outside. How do we handle such things without declaring the variable final?

Comment: I suppose the method you refer to, is a lambda expression...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the method onComplete(). This way (as a class member) you will be able to use it in multiple methods without it being a final.

For example:

```
static double number;
```